# Volumetrics not rendering/previewing in Cycles but working fine in Eevee

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

Hello Blender Stack Exchange! I seem to have a problem where my fog node setup doesn't display in the scene using Cycles engine (not working in 3D viewport nor in the final rendered image) but adversely, functions completely fine in Eeevee.

Here is what the Eeevee render looks like:
[image: You can clearly see the fog , especially off to the side.]

And here is the Cycles render:
[image: No fog is visible in this render.]

Here is my node setup for the fog:
[image: My node setup for the fog.]

Here is my .blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RtJDMypUyOUCXCq6r9403vBeg_xedTMs/view?usp=sharing (I hope Google Drive is a viable option for sharing .blend files.)

I have no idea what could be causing this issue, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I am no fog expert but as soon as I move camera out of fog it works... Not sure why, it happens to me sometimes as well, volume not working when camera is inside of the volume but only if it is outside... hope someone else will tell us why, but if you need it quickly just move it little so that camera wont be inside (worked for me)

Comment: Hmmm, I thought that Cycles was able to render volume inside the camera view since the 2.73 update.

Comment: @Emir Thank you for replying, but unfortunately, it does not. I think it has something to do with the camera being located in the volume parameters in MikoCG's answer, though. Certainly a dilemma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured out the problem. My normals on the volumetric box were flippped incorrectly. Simply flipping them did the trick and the volumetric shaders are working wonderfully in Cycles!